# Compatibility of source function in R

Tags: r

I am trying to execute together two lines above together but, on this way (when I selected both) is not working. When I select and run separately this code is works.

```
  SIMULATION<-data_edit(SIMULATION) 
                
  source(file=paste(path1,"/Simulation-Module.R",sep=""),local=TRUE)
```

When I selected this line together, this last line was not executed, while they worked when I selected it separately.
The first line with `data_edit` command comes from the library DataEditR. That command enables some editing of data.

So any can anybody help me how to solve this problem ? Do I need to set some additional argument ?

Comment: How exactly are you sending both lines to the console?  What exactly do you mean by "[second] line not executed"  ?  What does happen, what's the expected result, etc?

Comment: I selected lines and press Run with RStudio. The second line is  source(file=paste(path1,"/Simulation-Module.R",sep=""),local=TRUE). Separately works but together, not